# Using PHP Interface to modify HTML

Tags: php, html, dom

Any direction / help to this beginner would be so grateful.

I would like to create a interface that contains a title field.

The data entered into the interface title fields would be inserted into a html h1 title div.

Very simple, Im new to this, I read about using php to echo this, don’t have a full grip on this.

Here is an example of the html title code

```
<div class="col-md-12 titlebar">
   <h1 align="center">Place Title here</h1>
 </div>
```

This interface would allow the user to replace the html [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czG66.jpg)"Place Title here" with, any words they choose, "Car Show", "Hair Cut",.........

See attachment for simple illustration of interface.

Again, any direction, input, suggestion, examples….. would be so grateful, I can learn this quick with direction.

Thank you anyone and all.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. It's for fixing *existing* code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file you are modifying has the .php extension.
Begin the body of the file with <?php
Then you can simply echo the content inline...

```
<?php ?>

<div class="col-md-12 titlebar">
   <h1 align="center"><?php echo $_REQUEST['title']; ?></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Chris, I give this some time, Thank you for direction.

Answer (score 0):

A simple php file where you can start to learn (with 2 files):

out.php:

```
<div class="col-md-12 titlebar">
   <h1 align="center"><?php echo $_GET['input']; ?></h1>
</div>
```

form.html

```
<form method="GET" action="out.php">
  Title <input name="input" type="text"><br>
  <input type="submit" value"Confirm">
</form>
```

Comment: I can work on your suggestion for practice, I will need to find the correct method for the full html file is not a form. It is a large html file with many replacements just as this title. Im green here, therefore I dont know the correct terms for php.

Comment: Where the user set the words that you must set in HTML?

Comment: Yes the user will set the words in a interface that will output or set into the html. I did use the srt_ireplace() today. I like the fact that the php will find the string and replace with a value. My problem is i dont know how to enter this value into the str_ireplace() using a interface of some form. I attempted using the a form but failed on all attempts. Any direction would be so great.

Comment: You can do that like I make in the example: str_ireplace($_GET['input'], 'Place Title here') if the form is in the same page.

Comment: ok, i read at w3schools on how to use your suggestion str_ireplace($_GET['input'], 'Place Title here'). This seems simple, yet Im new to html and php, so I go slow. Any other direction you may think would direct me, I will read! Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Ok, I did read at W3Schools and I used your str_ireplace($_GET['input'], 'Place Title here') suggestion, I see this may place me closer to my goal, I keep you updated, this is really cool learning how this php works. Thank You for taking your time!

Comment: Conve - This str_ireplace($_GET['input'], 'Place Title here') will add the text just as you stated and as needed. How is it possible to have this php on separate page? Using the str_ireplace($_GET['input'], 'Place Title here') on same page renders the form on the page, the form is for building the page, how is it possible to place this str_ireplace($_GET['input'], 'Place Title here') on separate page while referencing the page that is being modified? Hope this makes sense, any direction is well taken. I will look on internet for answer also.

Comment: Fantastic.... I have found the solution by searching the web and it looks very close to your solution. I will test the solution I have found, confirming it works. Then I try your solution. I must say I was very excited to read w3schools and php-forum to mix what I read into a solution. I also am very happy you are helping, this is encouraging very much, makes me drive deeper. I report back here later to you on the progress. Very exciting learning this!!